# The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am not able to get rid of this error while returning `userData`. It says-- "The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'".

```
Future<User?> getUser({required String userId}) async {
    log.i('userId:$userId');

    if (userId.isNotEmpty) {
      final userDoc = await usersCollection.doc(userId).get();
      if (!userDoc.exists) {
        log.v('We have no user with id $userId in our database');
        return null;
      }

      final userData = userDoc.data();
      log.v('User found. Data: $userData');

      return User.fromJson(userData!); // This is where the error comes
    } else {
      throw FirestoreApiException(
          message:
              'Your userId passed in is empty. Please pass in a valid user if from your Firebase user.');
    }
  }
```

Below is my user model and I am using `json_serializable: ^6.2.0` and `freeze: ^2.0.3+1` in dev dependencies also `freezed_annotation: ^2.0.3` and `json_annotation: ^4.5.0` in dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` file. I am not getting where it is going wrong. Someone, please help me resolve this.

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'application_models.freezed.dart';
part 'application_models.g.dart';

@freezed
class User with _$User {
  factory User({
    required String id,
    String? email,
  }) = _User;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Firestore, you need to cast the object returned from `userDoc.data()` to `Map<String, dynamic>`:

```dart
final userData = userDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Here's an example from the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document